# Can I dynamically change polymorphic types with move semantics on multiple platforms?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, smart-pointers, move-semantics

So here's my dilemma:

I have a container which is going to store some objects. I'll interact with the objects in the container as if they were all of the base class. The base class is pure virtual. Some objects can be copied, and some can't. They're all movable though, so that's what I'm sticking with.

To give you an idea, I'm writing a container that is agnostic to accepting a custom shared_ptr and unique_ptr.

*All objects will be the same size, and this will be verified at compile time with static_asserts.*

I want to move objects around, and change the derived class type as I'm doing this. I'm guessing this is for the most part unsupported in any way, but I'm looking to see if there's enough definition to what I want to do that I can create a properly formed solution.

I want to avoid undefined at all costs, but implementation-defined, and unspecified behaviour is fine.

***Can I simply run a memcpy from one object to another in this case?*** If not, is there something else I can do to get this to work?

Comment: If the common size of all your types is `N`, how about a container of `std::aligned_storage<N, N>`?

Comment: "Some of them can't be copied"... "Use `memcpy` to copy them"...

Comment: @KerrekSB - does the memcpy work on all platforms?

Comment: Using `memcpy` with anything that's not trivially copyable is UB. Any class with virtual functions is by definition not trivially copyable.

Comment: @T.C. then I can treat the v-table pointer as an atomic pointer, and copy it that way. not worried about memcpy being UB here. looking for how v-tables are defined, and if they are in fact implementation defined meaning I could do this.

Comment: @MGaz The standard doesn't define how virtual functions are supposed to be implemented - with vtables or otherwise. Do what Kerrek suggested in his first comment and use `aligned_storage` and placement new.

Comment: @T.C. - yes, this is why I asked about implementation definitions. i'm writing my own storage container, aligned_storage will not work here. already using placement new.

Comment: Could be just me, but I have no idea, from your description, what you are trying to achieve. For one thing, `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` don't share a common base class, nor are they polymorphic, nor do they necessarily have the same size; so it's not clear why you mention them. What exactly do you mean by "change the derived class type"? Imagine that you somehow managed to implement the class you want; could you show an example of how you plan to actually use it?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - I mention the pointers to give an idea of what I'm trying to do. I wrote my own smart pointers using a custom allocator. Now I want to be able to send pointers around where the receiver doesn't know or care whether or not they're getting a unique_ptr or a shared_ptr. I don't like the idea of just using shared_ptr everywhere, as I prefer unique_ptr when possible... but there are some cases where I need a shared pointer as well. The example is coming :D